# How do i move an image/chart to a corner in Google Sheets without the awful margin?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get this image in a corner:

[image]

As you can see, when trying to move, Google puts an awful margin on the top which makes impossible to get an image on the very top of a document.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Try resizing your column/row so that it matches the image dimensions. If you can't eliminate white space, your source image probably includes some kind of white padding; try inserting the following image instead:

```
=IMAGE("http://www.buzzinbees.com/images/logos/buzzinbees.rect.2040.png")
```

and look at the resulting cell once you've resized it to match image dimensions.

If resizing column/row isn't an option, you may need to create an image that touches its left and top canvas and add white padding to the right and bottom of the image. Most image editors (free) can help you do that.